# Phaser.js Timed callback from a child in a group

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I would like for a child from a physics group destroy itself after ~2 seconds, along with other things, and I was thinking along the lines of a function callback which happens two seconds after the creation of the child, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

How do I call a function two seconds after a child is created, for any child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a custom `Sprite` class, that adds that specific functionallity, and than `create` or `add` the custom class to the `Group`.

**Here a short Demo:**
*(In this example the sprite will be destroy in 2 seconds after creation)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class TimerSprite extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {

    constructor (scene, x, y) {
        super(scene, x, y, 'img');

        let timedelay = 2000; // 2 seconds
 
         this.src = scene;           scene.time.delayedCall(timedelay, this.doSomething, null, this);
        
    }
    
    doSomething() {
        this.destroy();
        this.src._label.setText('update from sprite')
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 0 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this._label = this.add.text(10,10, 'DEMO TEXT')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('img', 10, 10);
    
    var group = this.physics.add.group( {
        classType: TimerSprite,
        //key: 'img'
    });
    
    // with group.create
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        group.create(10 + 10 * i, 50 + 10 * i);
    }
    
    // with group.add
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let sprite = new TimerSprite(this, 100 + 10 * i, 50 + 10 * i); 
        this.add.existing(sprite)
        group.add(sprite);
    }
    
    // create some childs abit later
    this.time.delayedCall(1000, () => {
        group.create(100, 100);    
    }); 
    
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works, but I can't access a group made in a different class, as I call a function which destroys the child, but makes new children for other groups, how do I access the other groups from a different class?

Comment: It also doesn't allow for any phaser objects, like, const emitter = this.add.particles

Comment: yes it does you need to use the passed `scene` parameter.

Comment: @VatsaPandey I updated my answer to show how.